# MYSQL JOIN data into json(object) array to a table with one field

Tags: mysql

I am new to MYSQL and I want to achieve this result.

For example, I have Table job,

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS job (
          job_id VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL unique,
          name VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
        ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

with data:

| jobId | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | test-job |

And then I have Table file,

```
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS file (
          job_id VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
          path VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
          name VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
        )
```

with data as shown below:

| job_id | name | path |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a.txt | D:/sourcefile/1/a.txt |
| 1 | b.txt | D:/sourcefile/2/b.txt |

I want to get this result as expected using MYSQL SELECT:

```json
{
  job_id: 1,
  name: 'test-job',
  files: [
    {
      name: 'a.txt',
      path: 'D:/sourcefile/1/a.txt'
    },
    {
      name: 'b.txt',
      path: 'D:/sourcefile/2/b.txt'
    }
  ]
}
```

I tried some solutions, but it is not working. Is there any good suggestion about this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

What backend you have? In MySQL u cant create custom array.
You can retrieve rows and groupy by job_id in backend.
U have any php/javascript code?